# Deeplearning4j to spark pipeline: Convert a String type to org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning, deeplearning4j

I have a sentiment analysis program to predict whether a given movie review is positive or negative using recurrent neutral network. I'm using Deeplearning4j deep learning library for that program. Now I need to add that program to apache spark pipeline.

When doing it, I have a class `MovieReviewClassifier` which extends `org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ProbabilisticClassifier` and I have to add an instance of that class to the pipeline. The features which are needed to build the model are entered to the program using `setFeaturesCol(String s)` method. The features I add are in `String` format since they are a set of strings used for sentiment analysis. But the features should be in the form `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT`. Is there a way to convert the strings to Vector UDT?

I have attached my code for pipeline implementation below:

```
public class RNNPipeline {
    final static String RESPONSE_VARIABLE =  "s";
    final static String INDEXED_RESPONSE_VARIABLE =  "indexedClass";
    final static String FEATURES = "features";
    final static String PREDICTION = "prediction";
    final static String PREDICTION_LABEL = "predictionLabel";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
        sparkConf.setAppName("test-client").setMaster("local[2]");
        sparkConf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
        JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(javaSparkContext);

        // ======================== Import data ====================================
        DataFrame dataFrame =    sqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                .option("inferSchema", "true")
                .option("header", "true")
                .load("/home/RNN3/WordVec/training.csv");

        // Split in to train/test data
        double [] dataSplitWeights = {0.7,0.3};
        DataFrame[] data = dataFrame.randomSplit(dataSplitWeights);



        // ======================== Preprocess ===========================



        // Encode labels
        StringIndexerModel labelIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol(RESPONSE_VARIABLE)
                .setOutputCol(INDEXED_RESPONSE_VARIABLE)
                .fit(data[0]);


        // Convert indexed labels back to original labels (decode labels).
        IndexToString labelConverter = new IndexToString().setInputCol(PREDICTION)
                .setOutputCol(PREDICTION_LABEL)
                .setLabels(labelIndexer.labels());


        // ======================== Train ========================



        MovieReviewClassifier mrClassifier = new MovieReviewClassifier().setLabelCol(INDEXED_RESPONSE_VARIABLE).setFeaturesCol("Review");



        // Fit the pipeline for training..setLabelCol.setLabelCol.setLabelCol.setLabelCol
        Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(new PipelineStage[] { labelIndexer, mrClassifier, labelConverter});
        PipelineModel pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(data[0]);

        }

  }
```

Review is the feature column which contains strings to be predicted as positive or negative.

I get the following error when I execute the code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column Review must be of type org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT@f71b0bce but was actually StringType.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnType(SchemaUtils.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PredictorParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(Predictor.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.validateAndTransformSchema(Predictor.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.transformSchema(Predictor.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$transformSchema$4.apply(Pipeline.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$transformSchema$4.apply(Pipeline.scala:167)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foldLeft(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline.fit(Pipeline.scala:121)
    at RNNPipeline.main(RNNPipeline.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: Possible? Sure. But without example data and an explanation what it represents it is rather unlikely someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

According to its [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/VectorUDT.html)

> User-defined type for Vector which allows easy interaction with SQL via DataFrame.

And the fact that in the [ML library](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html)

> DataFrame supports many basic and structured types; see the Spark SQL datatype reference for a list of supported types. In addition to the types listed in the Spark SQL guide, DataFrame can use ML Vector types.

and the fact you are asked for `org.apache.spark.sql.types.UserDefinedType<Vector>`

You can probably get away by passing either a `DenseVector` or `SparseVector`, created from your `String`.

The conversion from `String` (`"Review"` ??? ) to a `Vector` depends on how you have organized your data.

Answer (score 1):

The way to convert String type to verctor UDT is using word2vec. I have to add an word2vec object to the spark pipeline to do the conversion.